# Remove multiple fields from multiple shapefiles using a python script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2.8

I'm using the python console of QGIS 2.8.1-Wien.
I have a shapefile with many fields in the table that I want to remove them.
I tried to use this geoalgoritm as:

```
processing.runalg('qgis:deletecolumn', myshapefile.shp, "myfield", myoutput.shp)
```

This works perfectly and the field I want is removed.
My question is: if I want to remove more than one fields how should I write this formula? Or there are any other way to write a python script?

---

I used your 1st method, just for one shapefile as:

output_0=processing.runalg('qgis:deletecolumn', "D:/PATRICIA/ECMWF/Test/TPrecip_20140628_VERAO_join9.shp", "Lat_dec", None)
output_1=processing.runalg('qgis:deletecolumn', output_0, "Lon_dec", None)
output_2=processing.runalg('qgis:deletecolumn', output_1, "Altitude", "D:/PATRICIA/ECMWF/Test/TPrecip_20140628_VERAO_join12.shp")

The result was:"Error: Wrong parameter value: None"

I tried to use the 2nd method for 3 similar shapefiles (with same fields) activated in the table of contentes but just occured de removal of the fields in the 1st shapefile :

layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
res = layer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
layer.updateFields()

In this case it's impossible to use 8000 shapefiles activated in map canvas.

Any help?

Comment: I've edited my post, I think the `None` error was my mistake as I forgot to add a bit more to the code. Apologies for that! The edit includes a script to run on multiple shapefiles. You should probably edit your title as you want it for **multiple** shapefiles and not for a single one. Currently, your question is being flagged as a duplicate.